# NetBeans, how to call resourceBundle editor

Tags: netbeans, resourcebundle

for example I have
*ApplicationMessages.properties 
ApplicationMessages_ru_RU.properties*

used as resource bundle files for holding messages (localizations)

First time I created those two an editor showed up, displaying messages like this:
code -- standart -- ru_RU

the tab was closed, and now tabs are seperate and I don't know how to call it manually. I'm not sure how this editor is named so I'm not even sure what to search for.

so: how is it named and how to call for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on properties file and click on Open. Default action is edit as normal text.[image]

Comment: this is edit as normal text, but I asked for edit in bundle editor, or something (don't know name). you will then have --> key -- ru.value -- en.value -- other.value <-- table

Comment: No there are two action after right click. First action is Edit, this action open properties file as normal text. Second action is Open, which open resource bundle editor. I add picture with action after right click on properties file into answer.